# i2C controllable pulse generator

Tags: pwm, oscillator, i2c, pulse

I am trying to build circute where I can generate single pulse having width ranging from 1ms to 50ms and I would like to be able to control the width via i2c.
what I have done so far was using LED drivers such as PCA9550 where I can set the frequency and duty cycle and then activate or deactivate the adjusted chanel. The issue with this device is that I do not know when the first pulse will arrive. The activation can happen at the begining of the period, middle or end...(since there is no way to synchronize with the internal oscillator).

So I was wondering if anyone can recommend me something that I can control with i2c to generate pulses and activation will start with rising edge of the pulse. even single pulse generator would be ideal.

Comment: Welcome!  Have you considered a small processor, perhaps an ATtiny, for this?  The speeds are easily achievable, and interface over i2c in whatever way you want.

Comment: How about an MCU? But if you are already using an MCU to talk to another pulse-generating MCU, can you just use the MCU you already have to generate pulses?

Comment: @jonathanjo, yes I did conside using Attiny85 but the issue with that is I have to follow additional steps and circuit with another arduino to first program (SOIC 8)  and then add it to my supersmall PCB. I want something to add it to the designed PCB without furthur ptogramming beforehand

Comment: @Justme: This issue with my own MCU is that it only has 2 timers and they have resolution of 10ms ....

Comment: @Olmar Which MCU you have and what limits their resolution to 10ms (you likely don't mean resolution)? For 1 to 50ms range, what resolution you need, 1ms, 1us?

Comment: @Justme: I am using bluetooth module RN4871, with 3 timers: "Unit value for timer 1 is 640 ms, whereas for timers 2 and 3 are 10 ms." Ofcourse the best i can use are timer 2 and 3. And Im looking to control from 1ms to 50ms with 1ms steps only.

Comment: I believe the PCA9550 would do what you want and is probably available on a breakout board for Arduino and/or Raspberry Pi.

Comment: @Gil: As I mentioned the issue with PCA9550 is that once you assigne the lED0 or LED1 to blink at PWM rates defined in the registers, you dontknow when the first pulse is going to happen. if you set your frequency to 1Hz, after assignment, the first pulse can come in 1ms or 100ms or 500ms after you assign them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are unlikely to find the exact part you want as others have said.  Your constraint that you don't want a microcontroller is because a) space issues, a) prior programming requirement.  it appears that your upstream controller is an RN4871 bluetooth module.

My suggestion is to reconsider these constraints, perhaps in the following way.

**A) Solving size constraint** The smallest CPUs such as ATTiny 4/5/9/10 are available in SOT-23 packages: the size of a transistor.  You're not going to find many chips of any kind that are as small as this.

**B) Solving prior programming constraint.** If you have enough GPIO available, you could consider programming in-situ.  Your base requirement is SCL and SCD between CPU and pulse generator, plus an output pin for the pulse.  With one more GPIO pin to control the reset, you can organise to program an ATtiny over this interface.  (You'll need to be able to send the specific programming signals, which aren't i2c, over the wire, and you'll also need 5 V, but you don't say what power you have available.)

- Data - TPIDATA (SDA)
- Clock - TPICLK (SCL)
- Program - /RESET
- Pulse out - PB2

[image]
[From ATtiny 4/5/9/10 datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/ATtiny4-5-9-10-Data-Sheet-DS40002060A.pdf)

---

**PCA9550 Phase issue** You say this part is pretty much what you need execpt you don't know what phase you're going to get: you say there's no way to synchronise with the internal oscillator.  Did you try setting the output frequency to its maximum, then putting it to your required period just before you need it?  It might well be that a trick like this might get the part to do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You're unlikely to find a part on the market to generate a pulse whose width is controlled by I2C-accessible registers.

The IC manufacturers don't have a low-cost high-volume application or one with a safety requirement for this function. That means it can be done by the low-cost high-volume microcontrollers (MCUs) they already make to satisfy all manner of these functions their customers dream up.

The closest circuits would probably use:

- An I2C parallel I/O chip to control a digital timer IC plus gating ICs
- An I2C DAC to set the comparator threshold along with a voltage circuit

Both these are much larger circuits and more cumbersome than a single MCU, 8-pin or possibly 6-pin. As an aside, they're also much less flexible than an MCU if your requirements change.

You can use extra I/O to programme the firmware into the MCU on the board. That's then part of your selection criteria for an MCU.

Comment: The issue i have with MCUs is that I need a separate circuit just to program them and once done then I can add it to my tiny PCB and use i2c. in case i wana use SOIC package programing it and then adding it to another PCB would be a little bit challenging

Comment: @Olmar, you can look at In-System Programming (ISP), which I meant to put in this answer originally and have now added. But you know that you can't work forwards from a wish-list to a magic tiny IC, and that you have to work backwards from what's available and practical.